# Why I can't get update the state of my react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some issue trying to update the state of my react functional componenet.
I have set my componenet with my hook state like that.

```
function Tree(){


const [data,setData] = useState({
    id:1,
    label:'Root',
    children:[

    ],
    styles:{
        border:"1px solid green",
        padding:"10px 20px",
        position:"absolute",
        left:"45%",
        top:"20%",
  
      },
    content:{

    }
})




function addNode(parentId,nodeData){
    const newData = data;
    addChild(newData,parentId,nodeData)
    setData(newData);
}

function addChild(node,parentId,nodeData){
    if(parentId == node.id){
        
        node.children.push(nodeData);
        
     
         
    }else{
        //console.log("looking trough nodes")
        setNewState(node.children,parentId,nodeData)
    }
}

function deleteNode(nodeId){
    
}

console.log("rendering")

return (<>
    <Node children={data.children} styles={data.styles} addNode={addNode}></Node>
</>)
}
```

I am passing up the addNode method to the Node component through  props and in the node component just called it in a click event. Im also using a recursive function to get a new state value, there's no problem to create a new value  but I'd called out the state function and it doesnt rendering the component. I don't know what may be the reason  that the state doesnt got updated.
If some react exeprienced cant help me to resolve this problem, I'll be very greatfully with it.
The addNode function takes an id  and the value to add. The addChild method find the node recursively and pushed the value into itself children key.
pd: Sorry for my english if is not good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best practice to never mutate React state, which you are doing with `node.children.push` as `node` is a reference to the state `data`.

I would recommend that `addChild` should return a new object altogether that `setData` would be called with. Or I don't see why `addChild` couldn't call `setData` itself. But either way `data` should be cloned, and the clone is what should be mutated and passed to `setData`.

Also, with the functional nature of React, it is also best practice to not have functions mutate their parameters as `addChild` does.

Comment: Oh I see now, that really helped me a lot. That works perfectly, I solved it just clonning the data object with the Object.assign function. Thank you so much

Comment: glad to help, also, a lot of folks will use the spread operator to clone an objects like in Halil's answer: `const newObject = [...oldObject]` as shorthand for `Object.assign`.

Note that both of these functions only do a shallow clone, not a deep clone.

Also, just speaking from experience, I find it much easier to manage having many different calls to `useState` that each keep track of one thing, like 'label', 'id', 'children' etc. Instead of one call with a big state object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNode(parentId,nodeData){
   const newData = {...data};
   addChild(newData,parentId,nodeData)
   setData(newData);
}
```